# Routing Error, Michael Hartl's Screencasts from railstutorial.org

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, rails-routing, railstutorial.org

I am following Michael Hartl's Screencasts from railstutorial.org. According to chapter 5, I changed 
config/routes.rb to:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  match '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'
  match '/about',   :to => 'pages#about'
  match '/help',    :to => 'pages#help'
  root :to => 'pages#home'
end
```

and _footer.html.erb to:

- <%= link_to "About", about_path %>
- <%= link_to "Contact", contact_path %>

and _header.html.erb to:

```
 <% logo = image_tag("logo.png", :alt => "Sample App", :class => "round") %>
 <%= link_to logo, root_path %>
 <nav class="round">
    <ul>
      <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
```

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I am getting a Routing Error in the browser

No route matches "/pages/contact"

I am using ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-linux], 
rails 3.0.7 and gem 1.6.2
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routes are set up a level.  There is no route for /pages/contact, the correct route is "/contact" given your routes file.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. but i cant access my home page

Comment: Have you deleted public/index.html?  If not then that will always be served even if root :to is set in your routes.rb file.

Answer (score 0):

For late comers, I just had this same issue. The code from the tutorial shouldn't have an `end` after those `match` statements. If you look at the last line of config/routes.rb, you'll see and `end` there. That's the only end you need.

Instead of:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  match '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'
  match '/about',   :to => 'pages#about'
  match '/help',    :to => 'pages#help'
  root :to => 'pages#home'
end
```

It should be:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  match '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'
  match '/about',   :to => 'pages#about'
  match '/help',    :to => 'pages#help'
  root :to => 'pages#home'

 # All those commented out rules
 # All those commented out rules
 # All those commented out rules
end
```